# API Gateway how to configure GET request via SAM/Swagger/Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I want to configure a GET request using SAM/Swagger but find that I seem to be unable to do so. The [sample example provided](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/tree/a71fc92754624d722f3216826df97a73403a4b7a/examples/2016-10-31/api_swagger_cors) uses `x-amazon-apigateway-any-method` which creates a catch all API. So I seem to be unable to differentiate between GET/POST/PUT etc. How do I create individual APIs.

When I try swapping `x-amazon-apigateway-any-method` for `get`, the result API seem to be missing the lambda function integration

[image]

The `arn:aws:apigateway:ap-southeast-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:598545985414:function:${stageVariables.LambdaFunctionName}/invocations` stage variable used in the YAML appears to become invalid ... why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think something is invalid?

Most likely, the console shows only the name of the lambda function `${stageVariables.LambdaFunctionName}`, without the preifx `arn:...`.

When you executes a GET-request, AWS substitutes `${stageVariables.LambdaFunctionName}` with the value of this variable, this way getting the full correct name. Then AWS executes the lambda function.

Just make a GET request and get your "hello world".